# can't read a avatar pic mysite.com/storage/app/public/defaults/avatars/user.png 404 error

Tags: laravel

I am trying to retrieve users's avatar from storage "mysite.com/storage/app/public/defaults/avatars/user.png". But it s giving an error:

> Status Code: 404 Not Found

Tried to `php artisan storage:link` but it doesn't take any effect. Is there anything do I need to do about Storage. Because I actually doesn't understand why it's returning 404.

To explain the situation with more detail. I retrieving the user. the console log is like below.

```
avatar: "storage/app/public/defaults/avatars/user.png"
created_at: (...)
email: (...)
email_verified_at: (...)
id: (...)
name: (...)
role: (...)
```

And using the avatar in img tag.

```
<li><img :src="user.avatar" alt="ユーザー写真"> <h1>{{user.name}}</h1></li>
```

There is no problem at the name but the avatar. Storage response 404.

Comment: You can't access the storage directory from a browser. You need to execute `php artisan storage:link` to create the symbolic link between `storage/app/public` and `/public/storage`. Then change your avatar URL to `/storage/defaults/avatars/user.png`.

Comment: in the question I mentioned that I already executed `php artisan storage:link` @Ohgodwhy but it didn't worked.

Comment: Use Laravel storage facade : `\Storage::url($image_link)`

Comment: okay, if you explain where should I use it? it would be great, because I am returning avatar not in the blade but in the vue component... @Ivan

Comment: `\Storage::url($image_link)` will return a real file URL (string) like this `siteurl.com\storage\avatar\youravatar.png` so you should find the way to pass it into Vue component like HTML `data attribute`

Comment: You didn't pay attention to the part where I said `change the URL to /storage/defaults/avatars/user.png`. `app/public` is not in the URL from the `symlink`.

Comment: yep, sorry about that. it worked out. if you post it as answer I will check it. @Ohgodwhy